# how can i sort a Array(array.enumerated())

Tags: swiftui

I use this to sort the array, but it no working, and automatic it sort by using the element.name. I don.t know why?

```
ForEach(Array(array.enumerated()), id: \.element).sorted(by: {$0.element.date ?? Date() < $1.element.date ?? Date()} { (index,item) in

}
```

by the way,
and I use the @stateobject to state my core data entities

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @StateObject var array: arraycoredata
```

how can I sort it by using data?
any ideas?

Comment: In Core Data just add a sort descriptor to your fetch request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
        ForEach(Array(array.sorted(by: {$0.date ?? Date() < $1.date ?? Date()}).enumerated()),
                            id: \.element) { (index,item) in

        }
```

Comment: using the current date as a default value for nil is definitely not recommended. You should use distantFuture or distantPast depending if you want to sort the nil values to the beginning or the end of the collection.